# Pronuncia strana della "s" dopo una "r": un fenomeno romano o di tutta l'Italia?

Tags: pronunciation

Vivo a Roma da un po' di tempo e ho visto che la *s* a volte si pronuncia come una *z* sorda (cioè, /t͡s/) dopo una *r*. Alcuni esempi:

- *Persona* spesso si pronuncia come *perzona* o /pert͡sona/
- *Verso* come *verzo* o /vɛrt͡so/
- *Corso* come *corzo* o /kort͡so/

Ho anche visto che sebbene ci sia molta varietà interpersonale, non c'è praticamente varietà intrapersonale. In altre parole, non tutti pronunciano la *s* come una *z* sorda ma quelli che lo fanno, lo fanno quasi sempre. Non sono uscita molto da Roma quindi non so se in altre regioni si pronunci la *s* come una *z* sorda o meno.

- Quanto è comune pronunciare la *s* come una *z* sorda dopo una *r* (e forse dopo altre consonanti di cui non mi sono resa conto)?
- È un fenomeno limitato a Roma, o è una caratteristica dell'italiano standard?

Comment: Yay, ho corretto un paio di cose che non andavano bene. Inoltre, “ho vissuto a Roma da un po' di tempo” suona strano. Intendi “vivo a Roma da un po' di tempo” (e ci vivo tuttora) oppure “ho vissuto a Roma per un po' di tempo” (e quindi adesso non più)?

Comment: @DaG Intendo "vivo ancora a Roma". Grazie per le correzioni!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Confermo empiricamente che a Roma (e, direi, almeno parte del Lazio) è un fenomeno piuttosto comune, ed è ben noto ai linguisti, insieme agli altri che caratterizzano il consonantismo dell'italiano di Roma:

> Da segnalare, ancora in comune con la varietà toscana, oltre che con quelle meridionali, la resa dell’affricata sorda come fricativa in posizione intervocalica (*dice* è reso come [ˈdiʃe]) e, come in tutte le varietà meridionali, la pronuncia intensa di /b/ e di /ʤ/ intervocaliche (*su[bː]ito*, *ra[dːʒ]one*), con perdita delle non numerosissime opposizioni fonologiche proprie dello standard (*libra/libbra*; *agio/aggio*; *regia/reggia*). Entrambi i tratti sono diffusi anche in parlanti di livello medio e medio-alto; **lo stesso vale per la resa di /s/ con [ʦ] dopo /n/, /l/, /r/ (*pen[ʦ]o*, *fal[ʦ]o*, *bor[ʦ]a*, questa talvolta realizzata anche con la sonora), possibile anche in fonosintassi (*il [ʦ]indaco*, *non [ʦ]i sente*, *per [ʦ]icurezza*), che può neutralizzare opposizioni fonologiche e determinare errori ortografici (*via Portuen[ʦ]e* o, per ➔ ipercorrettismo, pomodori *San Mar[s]ano*)**.

(Paolo D’Achille, “[Roma, italiano di](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/italiano-di-roma_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/)”, in *Enciclopedia dell'Italiano*, Treccani)

Comment: Un articolo molto interessante! Ho anche identificato molte caratteristiche descritte nell'articolo ma non sapevo che fossero tipici del dialetto romano.